# Topology validate error

Tags: topology, arccatalog

[image]

Im using Arcmap 10.1 version.I don't know where i made mistake my database.
I have attached an example image to show the Error Report.

Comment: what do you want to do?which part did you get the error? please check again the feature classes you used and the rules you set.